# Can git be used reliably as an update / patch system for program installs?

Tags: git, deployment, installation, windows-installer

If so - does it work on a file level basis - or does it work lower - and only package what has changed.

I guess for this to work - the workstations would have to have git installed.

Comment: Git does not handle large binary files well. You really shouldn't be using it for that kind of thing.

Comment: Thank you.   I had begun to suspect that and your confirmation is apprecaited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git is not made for managing software installed in workstations! Of course it can be used for maintaining configuration synchronized between workstations, but then you'll need to develop the software for handling changes, installing stuff, reporting back, etc. This is a lot of work, and difficult to get it right.

You need a configuration management software like Puppet, Chef or CfEngine.

Comment: Thank you.  I appreciate your response. And I can easily see were trying to do would take more work than it would help.